# Projectile distance

Tags: physics

A ball is shot at a velocity of $10.0\ m/s$ at $40.0^\circ$ above the horizontal.  How far away does it land?

I know that the horizontal displacement equals time*horizontal velocity where here the horizontal velocity is $8\ m/s$. I don't know how to find the time.

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Comment: Can you just explain it? Tell me what do I need to find in order to get the time.

Answer (score 1):

Use Components!

$sin(40) (10)=6.43$

now that is the vertical component of velocity.

$d=v_i t +\frac{1}{2}a t^2$

when the ball lands, $d=0$

$0=6.435t-9.81 (0.5)(t^2)$   ($a$ is our acceleration and is equal to gravity)

which gives $t=0$ or $1.31$.

Ignore $t=0$ as that is when we are launching are projectile and take the other time.

Comment: I understand it now, but is there an easier way to find time using the equation? What I mean is, I'm not good at algebra and don't know how to find time when it's squared and such. Like, how do I simplify the equation d=vit +1/2at^2 in order to make it equal to time?

Comment: you can use the "quadratic formula". That is the simplest approach. I do not believe that there are any shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up some parametric equations.

$x = v_0\cos \theta\ t\\
y = v_0\sin \theta\ t - \frac 12 gt$

From here, you can either find the values of $t$ where $y = 0$ and then find $x(t)$

Or you can make an equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ and find $x$ without solving for $t.$

Answer (score 0):

The movement equations are given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle y(t) = v_{0}\sin(\theta)t - \frac{gt^{2}}{2}\\\\
\displaystyle x(t) = v_{0}\cos(\theta)t
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

When the ball reaches the ground, we have $y(t) = 0$, that is to say
\begin{align*}
y(t) = v_{0}\sin(\theta)t - \frac{gt^{2}}{2} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow t_{1} = 0\quad\vee\quad t_{2} = \frac{2v_{0}\sin(\theta)}{g}
\end{align*}

Finally, the displacement on the $x$-axis is given by
\begin{align*}
x(t_{2}) = \frac{v^{2}_{0}\sin(2\theta)}{g}
\end{align*}

Then plug in the given values in order to obtain the numerical answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the facts that the vertical component of the projectile’s velocity is zero at the top of its arc and that this occurs halfway through its flight to derive a very simple linear equation for $t$.